# Is this a bad OOP Approach for a multi tenant application?

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns

Will the following pattern be agile enough to evolve in a multi tenant SAAS application or is this a recipe for disaster?

This is using .net MVC 4 vs 2010

Approach:

All controllers inherit from a base class.
The base class makes 1 initialization of the db context which is passed to all services classes constructors of the implemented interface.

None of the services classes will call savechanges() on the db context as this will kill any type of transaction if involving multiple services. Thus any db transaction will be called in the controller.

Based on configuration of each tenant I will be able to use this logic to determine which implementation of each interface I will choose. Each controller has access to all service classes from inheritance. All services are passed to models to do each specific page logic.

Comment: what do agile have to do with it?

Comment: The most frequently used patterns for multitenancy are: a) Use a seperate DB per tenant. b) Use a TenantId column in every table.